# Could not find package codeigniter4/framework with stability stable

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, packagist, codeigniter-4

I'm doing exactly like what is suggested in the [official documentation](https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/index.html).

`composer create-project codeigniter4/framework`

However, I'm getting this error instead:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package codeigniter4/framework with stability stable.
```

I fully understand it is not stable yet but I'd like to try and develop a simple app for learning purpose since I've been using CI3 all this while. What should I do? This is the [closest possible answer](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-70670-post-353796.html#pid353796) to this question but it was left hanging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may install `develop` branch by:

```
composer create-project codeigniter4/framework:dev-develop
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for this clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Codeigniter 4** Moved to Production and also **updated** documentation in Feb 24,2020 you should try this code in composer

```
composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter project-root
```

Check the latest documentation 
[Codeigniter4 Documentation](http://%20https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/installing_composer.html)

Comment: Please check when this question was asked: in June 2018, there hasn't even been a first tagged alpha version

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PHP version is older than required in codeigniter4. please check whether your PHP version is **7.2(or higher)** or not. if you're running below 7.2 version of PHP you'll not be able to use codeigniter4.

Comment: Please check when this question was asked: in June 2018, there hasn't even been a first tagged alpha version. And at that time, there hasn't been such a requirement - the first alpha release was compatible with 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Check the php version you have installed globally,
using command php -v in cmd,
if it is below 7.2,
edit the php version in environmental variables.
**example: D:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.12**

this solved the issue I was facing while installing ci4 using composer,

have a good day.